# Porting an Android application to Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am seeking insight. I have a android application, and would like to create a ios port. Would it be easier to recreate the application in Xamarin, or would it be like starting over again? how alike are android, and Xamarin? thanks for any insight or advice. I am wondering if it might be easier to do this or to just do it sperately on ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to disassemble your Android app to see which parts are portable. That also gives you hints on how to move on for each parts.

**Android UI**
UI can be reused easily, as Xamarin.Android projects use the same XML format. So that you can create Xamarin.Android projects and then replace their UI with your existing Android UI.

**Third Party**
Third party SDK/components can be imported to Xamarin, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/xamarin-for-java/

Or some vendors already have their Xamarin libraries/components.

**General Java Code**
For general Java code you want to port, you can try Sharpen,

https://github.com/mono/sharpen

Good luck.