# Porting an existing Android project to WP and iOS in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

To my knowledge, Xamarin is cross platform framework, so I can build one app and share it to any platform (Android, iOS, and Windows phone). I can't find any documentation that demonstrate how to port an existing Android project (completed project) to other platform, What are portable parts in the project, and what parts that can't be ported? Could you please explain these points in simple words. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of useful resources when Googling `Porting an existing Android project to Xamarin`, including this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221790/porting-an-android-application-to-xamarin

Comment: Do you know  a good tutorial demonstrating this subject?

Comment: Nope. Xamarin seem to have some documentation on the issue though, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/

Answer (score 2):

When using Xamarin.Forms, projects are constructed in two parts:

- A PCL project which contains the shared code; this includes business logic and classes which define user interfaces for the application (these can be written using C# or XAML with a C# code-behind). These user interfaces are platform-agnostic as Forms defines elements which are common to all platforms (buttons, labels, entries, etc.), and those translate into the native controls on each respective platform.
- One or more platform-specific projects which contain boilerplate code to get the application up and running (such as the AppDelegate on iOS or MainActivity on Android), as well as any platform-specific behavior via the [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/), [custom renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/), or the recently added [effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/effects/introduction/). These three aforementioned features are not necessarily mandatory, but for times when you need to access platform-specific features, you may need to use one depending on your requirements.

See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) for a quickstart guide on how to get a Forms-based application up and running.